# C# Send text from Form2 textbox to Form1 Textbox

Tags: winforms, textbox, c#

I need some help, i want to set text from a textbox from Form2.cs to the another textbox in  Form1.cs but i keep getting this error:

```
Error 2 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property.
```

I'm coding in c# and i cannot find it anywhere on the internet how to do this?

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: you can call object of form1 from form2 and pass some value from constructor and change value as you required try this.

Comment: Do instances of both of your forms exist?

Comment: Also make sure the target control modifier is `public` and not `private` like it defaults to.

Comment: J0HN i would post my code but its not an open source project i'm working on, all i want to do is get text from one textbox to another on another form

Comment: @MatthewAllen While your business code might be disclosed the portion which tries to set the textbox text is properly generic enough to be posted here.

Answer (score 0):

you have to provide an istance of Form2 to Form1. Fore example you can pass it in the constructor like:

```
public Form2(Form1 frm)
```

and then you can call something like this

```
this.TextBox1.Text = frm.TextBox1.Text
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing this answer only based your error code.

1. You try to access a `non-static` method without using any instance of belongs it class object. For example; this code will fail.

> ```
> class Program
> {       
>    public static void Main()
>    {
>       WriteMethod();
>    }
>    public void WriteMethod()
>    {
>       Console.Writeline("Succes!");
>    } 
> }
> ```

But this code works;

```
class Program
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      Program p = new Program();
      p.WriteMethod();
   }
   public void WriteMethod()
   {
      Console.Writeline("Succes!");
   } 
}
```

Hope you get the main point.

Answer (score 0):

Well your case is too simple, you can do too many things in order to exchange data between classes

Why don't you try saving data in another static class, or a singleton one...

Answer (score 0):

```
//this code worked for me
//in form2 put following code prevent form from opening multiple times  
public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
             InitializeComponent();
        }
        private static Form2 Instance;
        public static Form2 GetInstance()
            {
                if (Instance ==null || Instance.IsDisposed)
           {
                Instance = new Form2();
            }
            else
            {
                Instance.BringToFront();
            }
                 return Instance;
         }

 // in form1

 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
             InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 form2 = Form2.GetInstance();
            form2.textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text;
            form2.Show();
        }
    }
```